# Calling the len() function that was inside a class in the main program, but there is an error

Tags: python-3.x, class

The len() method is inside function/method inside a class I created. When I try to call the function in my main program, it gives the error "for i in range (0, len(userlist)):
TypeError: object of type 'User_edit' has no len() "

I need the length the argument "string" for the loop to run as I need to tally the input with every item in the string.

I am a beginner so don't know much. so don't know much about what to do after that.

```
class User_edit():
    def __init__(self, userlist=[]):
        self.userlist=userlist
##snip other functions
#this function is used to login
    def login(userlist):
        print ("you are about to login to the system : ")
        username = input ("enter your username : ")

        password = input ("enter your password")

        for i in range (0, len(userlist)):
            if userlist[i]['username'] == username and userlist[i]['password']==password:
                print ("Login successfull \nwelcome to the system.")
                break
        else:
            print ("the username and/or password is incorrect")

## in the main program

import user_edit_class

userlist = [{'username': 'q', 'password': 'w'}, {'username': 't', 'password': 'd'}, {'username': 'v', 'password': 'o'}]

admin = {'username': "admin", 'password': "admin123"}

enter_admin = {}

user_edit = user_edit_class.User_edit(userlist)

identity = input("are you a user or and admin tyring to login?? ")
if identity == "user":
    user_edit.login()

##snip
```

I just expected to tally the input username with every username in the list(inside of the list of the dictionaries) and print "login successful" or "invalid username/password" depending upon the user input.

Comment: You should almost never use `for i in range(len(userlist)):` it's ugly and slower than the pythonic way of looping over collections `for user in userlist:`

Comment: thanks for suggestion. but i am trying to access dictionaries containing username and password inside the list and only using "for user in userlist" and truing to access the dictionary element as userlist['username'], gives an error "if userlist['username'] == username and userlist['password']==password:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" as in this case the value in the bracket it assumes i am trying to snip the list,, is there another way to access the dictionary elements?? any help appreciatred.

Comment: You should be using `if user['username'] == username` - __user__ not userlist

Comment: thank you very much.. once i understand if feel really stupid. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a conflict with names of variables..

See this piece of code:

```
    def __init__(self, userlist=[]):
    self.userlist=userlist
```

Here, you declare a class-level variable called userlist, taken in through the argument to the constructor.

Now here:

```
def login(userlist):
```

You take in the implicit self argument, and you also call it userlist. Now you have two things that are named the same. You have a reference to self called userlist, and you also have a reference to a list taken in through the constructor called userlist.

When you call:

```
len(userlist)
```

It assumes you want to call the len() function on the reference to self, because it is local scope which takes priority over class level scope. It tries to call len() on itself, and it doesn't have a len function.

So rename this local argument to anything besides userlist and it'll work. Probably call it 'self'.

In the future, try debugging problems like this by finding out what type the variable is. If you call print(type(userlist)) in your login method, it will tell you that the type of userlist is a User_edit. If you call print(type(userlist)) in the main section before calling login, it will tell you the type is a List. This means you are not referring to the variable that you think you are.

Comment: thank you,, I now understand that i named two things same.. it got solved just by defining the function as " def login(self,userlist): ". and called it with the argument "userlist " inside the main function.  i recon every definition of a method/function in side a class has to have "self" as an argument. i thought that was implicit, but aparently not.. so i thing defining the function that way got around the dual names..that is my understanding, if it is something else, i'd really appreciate if you explaind a bit.. thank you

Comment: That works, but there is no need to take in the userlist as an argument. You already have it as a class-level variable.

Answer (score 0):

When calling a method on an instance of a class, the first argument passed passed to the method is the instance itself. You defined the first parameter of `User_edit .login` as `userlist`, when the method is called this parameter is passed the instance not the list of users. The convention is to name this parameter `self`:

```
def login(self):
    print ("you are about to login to the system : ")
    username = input("enter your username : ")

    password = input("enter your password")

    for user in self.userlist:
```